# How to get a response from Api as a link to file?

Tags: java, spring, api

what can I do to get a response from Api like this instead as a base64string?:

[image]

this is a example for internet codeAnd this is reponse from my Api:

[image]

(this is a example for internet code)

I have no problem converting a string to a file but when I have many other files on reponse it takes time to get a correct response from API.

This is my file entity:

```
    @Entity(name = "file")
    public class FileEntity {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String fileId;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String originalName;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String fileName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String extension;
    @Lob
    private byte[] file;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cargo_id")
    private OrderEntity orderDetails;
}
```

Comment: You need to generate a link and return that. Currently I see you are returning the @Lob private byte[] file; which is the file itself, hence converted to base64

Comment: @CurssedHammer how can I generate a link ?

Comment: I just added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to return such links would be to get some id for the file and return URL for another GET API to get files by ID.

As in the above case: http://localhost/files/{fileId}
This new API would then get the actual file(maybe as base64) whenever executed.

Let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: It got me a little bit. I'll try to do something about it and I'll be back with the answer :)